# How to concat in mule or dataweave?

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a requirement where i get mail address like jon's@gmail.com. But while sending to salesforce i need to send like jon\'sram@gmail.com .

This is the scenario where i need to use.

```
SELECT Email,Id FROM Contact WHERE Email = 'jon\'sram@gmail.com'
```

Now the scenario is like below, but what happen here email address contain single quot where it is failed.

```
SELECT Email,Id FROM Contact WHERE Email = 'jon'sram@gmail.com'
```

i have tried in different ways but they seems complected.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use below expression in "Set Payload" to original string:

```
#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String).replace("'","\\\'")]
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to concatenate you can use the ++ operator "Foo" ++ "bar" . Also take into account that in DW string can be represented by either " or ' . In your case I would say that you need to type 'jon\\'sram@gmail.com' so that it will end up generating what you want. Regards